# Find-like utility to walk *up* directory tree

Tags: command-line

If I want to find a file in a directory or somewhere under it, `find` is a very useful utility.  Is there a similar utility that will find things in the current directory or above it?

For example, if my file system looks like this:

```
/proj/
   foo/
     pom.xml
     bar/
       pom.xml
       baz/
         pom.xml
   quz/
     pom.xml
```

then `find /proj/foo/bar -name pom.xml` will give me

```
/proj/foo/bar/pom.xml
/proj/foo/bar/baz/pom.xml
```

as it's output.  I am looking for a command that would return

```
/proj/foo/bar/pom.xml
/proj/foo/pom.xml
```

(or the opposite order).  What I currently tend to do is write a shell script that does something like

```
while [[ $dir != / ]]
do
  check stuff
  cd ..
done
```

Does something like this exist?

Ideally, I would like something that works on Linux, Mac and Cygwin in any shell, but something that works on a subset, or only in `bash`, is also useful.

Comment: Aaah...I misunderstood the request then.

Comment: I think this is interesting and like the question.... Maybe this will help give you a starting point or you'll see a solution there that will suffice for your need: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6463/find-searching-in-parent-directories-instead-of-subdirectories The accepted answer looks similar to your while loop example with some addition stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but this should do it in `bash` (not sure about other shells):

```
#!/bin/bash
oldpwd=`pwd`
ret=1

while true; do
    find `pwd` -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 $@

    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        ret=0
    fi

    if [ `pwd` = '/' ] ; then
        exit $ret
    else
        cd ..
    fi
done

cd $oldpwd
```

As a script, it should accept regular `find` syntax for expressions.  It saves off the current directory so it can jump back later, and then loops up the directory tree, searching only items at that level for the expression, up until it hits the root directory.  This will print all matching items up the tree, you could easily add a check inside the loop to bail if `find` is successful if you just want the first matches.

It could probably be optimized a bit, but I went for quick and easy to understand over speed.

Comment: Since it is running in a script, there should be any need to cd back to the original directory at the end.